# Android notifications : why my notification so small?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, notifications, google-play

I created a notification following the instructions [given here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification) (same code).

My problem is that my notification looks very small like these:

[image]

and not normal size like here:

[image]

Do you know how to have 'normal size' notifications ?

Thanks !

Here is the code:

```
 private void showNotif() {

            createNotificationChannel();

            String title = "Hi guys !";
            String txt = "How are you ? :)";

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(txt)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(txt))
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);


            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

// notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
            notificationManager.notify(2, builder.build());





    }


    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "XXXXXX"; // getString(R.string.channel_name);
            String description = "XXXXXXX"; // getString(R.string.channel_description);
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(AlarmBroadcastReceiver.CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
            // or other notification behaviors after this
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add the code here, even if it's an example. Links can rot. Link to the source to cite it, but code goes in the question.

Comment: Code just added !

Comment: Such behavior is standard for Android OS. All notifications except top notification will be presented in minimized view. You can make long tap or tap on down arrow to maximize notification.